Dapper Update syntax error not triggering catch block
In the following update function, there is a syntax error in the parameter naming. I know what's wrong, so can correct it, however when the code is run, my application just hangs on the ExecuteAsync statement - neither of the catch blocks are triggered as I would have wanted?
   public async Task<TbiResult> Update(Customer customer)
    {
        TbiResult res = new();
        try
        {
            var sql = @"UPDATE Organisation SET
                      ORG_Owner_ORG_Id=@Org_Owner_ORG_Id,
                      ORG_Type=@Org_Type,
                      ORG_Status=Org_Status,
                      ORG_Code=@Org_Code,                          
                      ORG_Name=@Org_Name,
                      ORG_CUR_Id=@Org_CUR_Id,                          
                      ORG_SalesPriceChaseDelayDays=@Org_SalesPriceChaseDelayDays,
                      ORG_SalesTargetMarginPercentage=@Org_SalesTargetMarginPercentage,
                      ORG_Address1=@Org_Address1,
                      ORG_Address2=@Org_Address2,
                      ORG_Address3=@Org_Address3,
                      ORG_Address4=@Org_Address4,
                      ORG_City=@Org_City,
                      ORG_County=@Org_County,
                      ORG_PostCode=@Org_PostCode,
                      ORG_COU_Id=@Org_COU_Id,
                      ORG_PaymentDueDays=@ORG_PaymentDueDays,
                      ORG_DiscountType=@DiscountType,
                      ORG_DiscountAmount=@DiscountAmount,
                      WHERE ORG_Id=@Org_Id AND ORG_Timestamp=@ORG_Timestamp";

            DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Owner_ORG_Id", 0, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);         
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Type", TbiConstants.orgtype_customer, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Status", TbiConstants.orgtype_customer, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);                                                                       
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Code", customer.ORG_Code, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);                
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Name", customer.ORG_Name, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_CUR_Id", customer.ORG_CUR_Id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);                
            parameter.Add("@ORG_SalesPriceChaseDelayDays", customer.ORG_SalesPriceChaseDelayDays, DbType.Int16, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_SalesTargetMarginPercentage", customer.ORG_SalesTargetMarginPercentage, DbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Address1", customer.ORG_Address1, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Address2", customer.ORG_Address2, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Address3", customer.ORG_Address3, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_Address4", customer.ORG_Address4, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_City", customer.ORG_City, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);                
            parameter.Add("@ORG_County", customer.ORG_County, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);                                                                
            parameter.Add("@ORG_PostCode", customer.ORG_PostCode, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_COU_Id", customer.ORG_COU_Id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_PaymentDueDays", customer.ORG_PaymentDueDays, DbType.Int16, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_DiscountType", customer.ORG_DiscountType, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameter.Add("@ORG_DiscountAmount", customer.ORG_DiscountAmount, DbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);

            res.Rowsaffected = await TbiConstants.gblconn.ExecuteAsync(sql,parameter,TbiConstants.gbltrans) .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (res.Rowsaffected == 1)
            { 
                res.Status = "Y";                    
                res.Id = customer.ORG_Id;
                res.Message = "Customer updated";
                res.Details = null;
                return res;
            } 
            else 
            { 
                res.Status = "N";                    
                res.Id = customer.ORG_Id;
                res.Message = "Customer record has been changed by someone else. You will need to redo your change(s) and try Saving again";
                res.Details = null;
                return res;
            } 
        }
        catch (SqlException quex)
        {
            res.Status = "F";                                    
            res.Id = customer.ORG_Id;
            res.Message = quex.Message;
            res.Details = quex.InnerException.Message;
            return res;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            res.Status = "F";                                    
            res.Id = customer.ORG_Id;
            res.Message = ex.Message;
            res.Details = ex.InnerException.Message;
            return res;
        }            
    }

If I run in debug mode I can see that an sqlexception is thrown, so I'm puzzled as to why the app just hangs (when the query is actually executed) rather than invoking the catch block?
Cheers
Reg
